# Is Ubuntu 10.04 compatible with Toshiba L640D

Tags: installation, ati, compatibility

Will Ubuntu 10.04/10.10 work on a [Toshiba L640D](http://www.toshiba-india.com/laptop/satellite-L640D.html)? I mean, I am going to install it on Sunday, but just wanted to know before hand if I will encounter any problems (read ATi). I looked up the [Ubuntu Certified Devices](http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Toshiba/), but I did not find the model listed. Any users with the said configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very similar configuration on my lenovo z560. the only difference is that it uses nvidia instead of ati. Ubuntu installed without a glitch. so i dont think there would be any problem. Of Course if you do run into one you can always ask here :D

Comment: the ati is the biggest problem. even i run ubuntu on amd at home, but its a nvidia agp. so i have no idea/experience about ati. but, ill ask here anyway :)